# jquery - intercept, calculate and show in real time the list boxes choices

Tags: jquery, listbox, real-time, intercept

I've got a simple and elementary jquery function for calculate the quantities * unit prices + taxes and subtotals for some products and then the total. I wish to show, in real time, with jquery, the taxes imports for the different taxes rates, based on user choices in the list boxes. I found an elementary method for 2 products but for 3 or many, my method doesn't work: please help me? ;)

This is my code: demo is [here] http://jsfiddle.net/skipperit/px9tb/8/

```
<script type='text/javascript'> 
$(function(){
$('#q1,#pu1,#tax1,#tax2,#q2,#pu2').change(function() {
var q1 = parseFloat($('#q1').val(), 10);
var qval1 = 0;
if (q1 > 0) {
    qval1 = q1;
}
var q2 = parseFloat($('#q2').val(), 10);
var qval2 = 0;
if (q2 > 0) {
    qval2 = q2;
}


var pu1 = parseFloat($('#pu1').val(), 10);
var puval1 = 0;
if (pu1 > 0) {
    puval1 = pu1;
}

var pu2 = parseFloat($('#pu2').val(), 10);

var puval2 = 0;
if (pu2 > 0) {
    puval2 = pu2;
}

var subtot1 = 0;
subtot1 =  parseFloat(qval1 * puval1);
var subtot2 = 0;
subtot2 =  parseFloat(qval2 * puval2);
var subtot = 0;
subtot = subtot1 + subtot2;
var tax1 = parseFloat($('#tax1').val(), 10);
var tax2 = parseFloat($('#tax2').val(), 10);
var ivaprice1 = 0;
var ivaprice2 = 0;
if (tax1 > 0) {

    ivaprice1 = subtot1 * tax1 / 100;
}
if (tax2 > 0) {

    ivaprice2 = subtot2 * tax2 / 100;
}
 var ivaprice = 0;
 ivaprice = parseFloat(ivaprice1 + ivaprice2);
var ivatext = "";
ivatext = "tax ";

$('#total').html(parseFloat(subtot + ivaprice).toFixed(2));
$('#tasse').html(parseFloat(ivaprice).toFixed(2));
$('#imp').html(parseFloat(subtot).toFixed(2));
$('#subtot1b').html(parseFloat(subtot1).toFixed(2));
$('#subtot2b').html(parseFloat(subtot2).toFixed(2));

if (tax2 == tax1) {
    $('#taxw').html(parseInt(tax1));
    $('#taxtxt2').html('');
    $('#taxw2').html('');
    $('#taxv').html(parseFloat(ivaprice).toFixed(2));
    $('#taxv2').html('');
    $('#taxtxt2b').html('');
}
else
{
    $('#taxw').html(parseInt(tax1));
    $('#taxw2').html(parseInt(tax2));
    $('#taxtxt2').html('tax');
    $('#taxtxt2b').html('%:');
    $('#taxv').html(parseFloat(ivaprice1).toFixed(2));
    $('#taxv2').html(parseFloat(ivaprice2).toFixed(2));
 }

});
});  

</script>


</head>
<body>
<p>q1 : 
<input id="q1" value="0"/>

pu1 :
<input id="pu1" value="0"/> 
tax1:
<select name="tax1" id="tax1">
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="21">21</option>
<option value="16">16</option>
</select>
</p>
<p>q2 :
<input id="q2" value="0"/>
pu2 :
<input id="pu2" value="0"/>
tax2 :
 <select name="tax2" id="tax2">
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="21">21</option>
<option value="16">16</option>
 </select>
 <br>
<br>subtot1: <span id="subtot1b"></span><br>
 subtot2: <span id="subtot2b"></span><br>
tax <span id="taxw"></span>%: <span id="taxv"></span><br>
<span id="taxtxt2"></span> <span id="taxw2"></span><span id="taxtxt2b"></span>    <span    id="taxv2"></span><br>

 taxable: €<span id="imp"></span><br>
 Tax: €<span id="tasse"></span><br>
 Total price : €<span id="total"></span></p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/WpN6S/)

**html:**

```
​<div id="uguu" data-row="5"></div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

**js:**

```
$(function() {
    (function($) {
        $.fn.extend({
            autobotTransform: function() {
                return this.each(function() {
                    // variables
                    var _this = $(this);
                    var prodCount = _this.attr("data-row");
                    var _opt = '<option value="4">4</option><option value="21">21</option><option value="16">16</option>';

                    // set-up
                    for (i = 1; i <= prodCount; i++) {
                        _this.append('<p class="priceRow">q' + i + ' :<input id="q' + i + '" value="0" />' +
                                     'pu' + i + ' :<input id="pu' + i + '" value="0" />' +
                                     'tax' + i + ':<select name="tax' + i + '" id="tax' + i + '">' +
                                     _opt + '</select>'
                                    );
                    }
                    for (i = 1; i <= prodCount; i++) {
                        _this.append('subtot' + i + ': <span id="subtot' + i +'"></span> ' +
                                     'tax <span id="taxw' + i + '"></span>%: <span id="taxv' +
                                     i + '"></span><br>'
                                    );
                    }
                    $("input, select", _this).on("change", function() {
                        $('p.priceRow').each(function(index) {
                            var __this = $(this);
                            var i = index + 1;
                            $("#subtot" + i).html(
                                ((($("#q" + i).val() > 0) ? parseFloat($("#q" + i).val(), 10) : 0.00)
                                * (($("#pu" + i).val() > 0) ? parseFloat($("#pu" + i).val(), 10) : 0.00)).toFixed(2)
                            );
                            $("#taxw" + i).html($("#tax" + i).val());
                            $("#taxv" + i).html(($("#subtot" + i).html() * $("#tax" + i).val() * 0.01).toFixed(2));
                        });
                    }).trigger("change");
                });
            }
        });
    })(jQuery);

    $("#uguu").autobotTransform();​
});
```

Comment: Hi @Kei very useful and interesting solution: isn't exactly what I like to do but it's very close to my desires; your code is fantastic! I just have to make a routine that adds taxes with equal rates, in real time...

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a complete answer, as there's too much going on there with too many variable names that I don't understand. Hopefully it will be of some use though.

**Step 1:** Add a class to any field which, when changed, should trigger recalculation. This will enable you to make a single jQuery selector for all of them, e.g.:

```
<input id="q1" value="0" class="change-trigger" />
```

and

```
$('.change-trigger').change(function() { ... });
```

**Step 2:** As it seems you need to recalculate everything on any change, you could try reading the values from the relevant fields into an object, and storing the objects in an array, something like (inside the handler function above):

```
var allValues = [];
$('.change-trigger').each(function(idx) // do something with all .change-trigger elements
{
    var values = {};
    values.q = Math.max(0, parseFloat($('#q' + idx).val(), 10));
    values.pu = Math.max(0, parseFloat($('#pu' + idx).val(), 10));
    values.tax = Math.max(0, parseFloat($('#tax' + idx).val(), 10));
    values.pretaxtotal = values.q * values.pu;
    values.taxtotal = (values.pretaxtotal * values.tax) / 100;
    values.linetotal = values.pretaxtotal + values.taxtotal;

    allValues[idx] = values;
}

// later calculations using a loop over the allValues array, e.g.
var taxBandTotals = [], lowTax = 100.0, highTax = 0.0, taxIndex;
for (var i = 0; i < allValues.length; i+=1)
{
    // sum up each tax band by adding to index [tax%] in array
    if (allValues[i].tax > 0)
    {
        lowTax = Math.min(lowTax, allValues[i].tax);
        highTax = Math.max(highTax, allValues[i].tax);
        taxIndex = parseInt(allValues[i].tax, 10);

        // initialise to 0

        if (taxBandTotals[taxIndex] === undefined)
        { taxBandTotals[taxIndex] = 0; }

        // add this entry's tax to the right slot
        taxBandTotals[taxIndex] += allValues[i].taxtotal;

    }

    // aggregate values into totals etc.
    // could play with loop variable to look ahead/behind for
    // comparison with other tax values?
}

for (var j = parseInt(lowTax, 10); j <= parseInt(highTax, 10); j+=1)
{
    if (taxBandTotals[j] !== undefined)
    {
        // this is a total for tax % "j"
    }
}
```

**Step 3:** Remove the `CDATA` stuff, it's not necessary any more :)

Comment: hi Matt, many thanks for your tips and I'm sorry for my tangled question: they are very useful tips... also for the future: now the code is more clean and pro. The only thing is.. that I'd like a routine to show or not the taxes amounts divided by rates..I add the demo ..Look what happens if you change the values ​​of the listbox... if they are equal to each other or not...thanks

Comment: Ah yes, I can see what you're saying. Once you have the monetary tax value for each row, you want to calculate the total amount of tax in each percentage group. Edited my answer to add that in, hope it helps.